# Trim image by color

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design

I have an image:
[image: must be trimmed]

I need this image for a webpage background. As you see, it has lots of useless pixels around the blurred element which could be replaced with CSS.

The image given to me is JPG, I have no access to layers.

Is there a way to trim by color instead of transparent pixels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Photoshop gives you the option to trim an image based on the top left pixel or the bottom right pixel.

1. Open the image in Photoshop
2. Select Image > Trim... from the menu
3. Choos either top left or bottom right options and click 'OK':

[image: Trim dialogue box in Photoshop CS6]

Comment: Woah, can't believe I missed that one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can make a selection based on the background color:
select/color range...

after you have done that you can either simply delete the background or create an image mask (gives you more edit options).

Save as a PNG with transparency and set the background of your web site to the same as the original background color.